# How do i display the result of this function in a DIV element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant figure out how to display the result of this function, in an element. I created a DIV and id tagged it. Then selected it in Javascript, ran innerHTML and tried to make it equal to sum, from the function. Throws an error. If I console.log sum within the function, it returns the value just fine. Could i have some suggestions for how to display this number in an element in HTML? Heres my code:

```
document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = sum;


function getSum() {
const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
    }
}
```

}

```
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="date" name="" value="" id="dateInput">
    <button onclick="getSum()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: So where's the code where you ran `innerHTML` ?

Comment: it didnt post in my OP, i corrected it. Its at the top.

Comment: when i tried to put it in the function, it threw an error. Maybe I just didnt place it in the correct spot?

Comment: Remove the hash `#`, then try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the line that sets the `.innerHTML` at the bottom of the function that calculates `sum` and remove the `#` when using `.getElementById()`. And really, if the value you are working with doesn't contain any HTML, then don't use `.innerHTML` as it has performance and security implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

```js
function getSum() {
  const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        sum += num;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").textContent= sum;
}
```

```html
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="date" id="dateInput">
    <button onclick="getSum()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Im getting confused on the proper syntax, i have seen it written with the #, when manipulating DOM outside a function. DO the rules change if I do it within the function (needs to be without the identifier)?

Comment: The function is called `getElementById` - you don't need to tell it again it's an ID, which is what the `#` is conventionally used for

Comment: @nineborn You only use `#` when referencing an element's `id` from CSS or when using `.querySelector()`, but never with `.getElementById()` because as the method's name suggests, it already knows it's looking for an `id`. Don't Forget to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: thank you Scott, i appreciate it. And thanks for the tip on using textContent. Im a newb.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle (edited version of your code) - https://jsfiddle.net/6g93khy1/

Please note that getting the element by id should happen like this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set the value at the end of your function, because the value isn't refreshed in your case.

Just add the first line :

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum;
```

at the end of your function :)